# CiviMail stuck on "Starting execution of Send Scheduled Mailings"

Tags: civimail

WordPress installation. Upgraded web hosting to a VPS (Site5) and they said the cron job would work fine. I sent a test of this mailing to a group of 10. It worked fine. I So I sent the mailing to a group of ~4236 recipients and executed the "Send Scheduled Mailings." That was over an hour ago. The job log says:

Entity: Job Action: process_mailing
Summary
Starting execution of Send Scheduled Mailings
Details

Parameters parsed (and passed to API method): 
a:1:{s:7:"version";i:3;}

Full message: 
Starting execution of Send Scheduled Mailings

Should I be worried or does this just take a long time?

Answer (score 1):

so you should have the report accessible for this mailing, what do you see? you have the number of emails delivered, that should increase, more or less slowly depending on how you configured your cron

Comment: It looks like in the mailing details report all 4237 went but the Send Scheduled Mailings is still stuck on "Starting execution" and I never got a "Finished execution of Send Scheduled Mailings with result: Success (a:0:{})" message. I guess this why there's not a summary report for this job? Thanks for your help!